# working with maven to run java class files

Tags: java, maven-2, compilation

I am new to Maven
My question is where does maven download the external dependency jars in the local machine.

Basically my application uses a lot of external dependencies and i am able to compile the application using maven

But is there a way to run the application from commandline with Java without having to create a Jar-with-dependencies, basically by just using all the class files and specifying my main class. For that i will have to set the classpath to the directory where my external jars are located. How do i do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the [exec maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run your application inside the maven lifecycle. In its simplest form the command would be

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.Main
```

The full set of configuration options are described on the [exec:java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) page. The `classpathScope` option might be especially interesting.

The advantage of this method would be that you can [configure any command line arguments and system properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) in your pom file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) to ask maven for the classpath. Just run

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

and you can use the output in your `java -cp` command.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:

> My question is where does maven download the external dependency jars in the local machine.

Your local repository is usually here (on a Windows machine)

```
C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository
```

Read more about Maven settings (especially the `localRepository` setting):

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html